# How to debug the Publish Test Results Azure DevOps plugin locally?

Tags: azure-devops

This plugin is supposed to support NUnit test results, but the support leaves a helluva lot of space for improvement. The plugin does not:

1. Preserve test output for successful test cases (they say it is by design - https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8979 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/432166/the-publish-tests-azure-devops-plugin-should-publi.html)
2. Does not preserve test attachments for successful test cases (same by design - https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9093)
3. Does not compute total duration correctly when merging test results (NUnit3 + NUnit2 - https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8981)
4. Show the full name of a test case consistently (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9497 and https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9499)

The test case name display is especially problematic for me.

In short, it is a torture to use. I would like to see if I can debug it and figure out how it works, because maybe by doing some transformations on the test result XML I could work around some of the bugs. Like I do with the test output - it can be worked around for the NUnit3 test results (but not for MSTest).

Answer (score 1):

The source code appears open source @ [azure-pipelines-tasks/Tasks/PublishTestResultsV2](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PublishTestResultsV2).  If you install a local agent, one of the first things that happens is the task download.  That gets installed into your _work\_tasks folder.  I'd assume you could compile and overwrite at that local agent location _task directory, attach a debugger in some fashion, and then just target your local registered agent for it to pick-up and process the job.

Comment: Devil is in details and I assume there are many. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: The debug output of the plugin indicates that it does nothing except execute certain undocumented VSTS logging commands. It calls some kind of Feature Flags API which tells it not to use the binaries that come with the plugin. I have no idea how to debug the logging commands, seems too much of a fuss at this point. So, I abandoned the idea.